# Visual Studio hot keys change occasionally, specifically F6 vs Ctrl-Shift-B for building. WHY?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I always press <kbd>F6</kbd> to build my project.  Suddenly some of my Visual Studio instances are wanting me to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>.  It's not keyboard related - the actual text of the menu option changes from "<kbd>F6</kbd>" to "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>".

Any answers as to how to fix, and **what causes this**?

Comment: Any chance you have a fancy 'media' keyboard with FnLock stuck on?

Comment: I attest to this. It has happened with my VS as well several times, and I did reset to VS 05 scheme inspite that it was already set. Just like you I am left wondering why and how this happens, and how to avoid it

Comment: @Joel no, it's a mapping change within VS2008.  Perhaps related to me always having 4-6 instances open?  Suddenly half of them have this issue, and all new ones do.  Maybe closing all, opening one, resetting, closing it, then reopening all will fix?!  But that doesn't explain the WHY??!!?!?

Comment: @Vin thanks.  May I ask you - do you keep multiple instances open a lot?  ScottCher suggests it's related to a corruption when many instances are messing with settings.  Sounds flakey, but that's one thing I do that others don't.  I ALWAYS have 4-6 instances running.

Comment: I thought Ctrl+Shift+B was the default mapping anyway...

Comment: lol seems to have cropped up again VS2013 F6 no longer works

Comment: With VS2008 I always had to be careful not to close two instances of VS at the same time. They'd both be writing the settings and this might mess things up. With VS2013 it seems better though, although I'm still a bit careful.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is because you might have selected "General Development Settings" as your default environment settings for your Visual Studio (which usually we do on the first launch of VS after installing it as it pops up a dialogue box to choose default environment settings).

If you only want to change the keyboard hotkeys settings, you just follow the solution proposed by others (**Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > Visual C# 2015**). ***BUT*** this will only change the keyboard settings to C# settings while keeping rest of the settings as General settings only.

If you are really intending to change complete environment to C# settings, then follow this approach.

**SOLUTION 1:**

1. Go to "Tools" (menu)
2. "Import and Export Settings"
3. "Import selected environment settings"
4. Either select "Yes, save my current settings" or "No, just import new settings, overwriting my current settings"
5. "Which collection of settings do you want to import?"
6. Under "Default Settings" tree select "Visual C#" node (you might see a yellow warning sign, NO need to worry about it) and then click "Finish" button.

or you can do the same like

**SOLUTION 2:**

1. Go to "Tools" (menu)
2. "Import and Export Settings"
3. "Reset all settings"
4. Either select "Yes, save my current settings" or "No, just import new settings, overwriting my current settings"
5. Select "Visual C#" from the list and then click "Finish" button.

Both approaches would give you the same result of changing your complete environment to 'Visual C#" there onward.

Enjoy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks so much, best answer here! BTW to reset ONLY the keyboard settings, use Solution #1 but then on the final "Choose Settings to Import" screen, unselect "All Settings" and choose only Options -> Environment -> Keyboard.

Answer (score 68):

Keyboard mapping corruption issue perhaps?  Check Tools / Options, Environment / Keyboard.  Should see a drop-down for your Keyboard mapping scheme and next to it a Reset button.  Hit the reset button.

I'm not responsible for this screwing with your settings - save them prior to doing this just in case you screw the pooch.

Oh, in case the narcs out there care, I think this is a valid question and would be put out if someone voted to close it.  Of course now that I've said that, its a certaintity, isn't it?

Comment: OK, "Reset" fixed it, even though it was already set to C#2005.  Now the question is - What makes it change?  This has happened to me a lot over the years.

Comment: in VS2013 F6 no longer seems to be default so reset does not work :(

Comment: @markmnl Make sure you choose "Visual C# 2005".  The (default) mapping scheme didn't change it for me.  Odd thing for me was I had F6 with VS2013 Ultimate, but not with VS2013 Premium.

Comment: This is not a solution because I need to know why VS goes apes**t and removes shortcuts... happened to me today on VS 2015

Answer (score 57):

Your keyboard scheme has changed - go to Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard and set the default keyboard scheme to 'Visual C# 2005'

Comment: @AlekseyBykov if the C# keyboard scheme has *changed*, you will also need to reset it,

Comment: For VS 2013 premium check the answer from @CYBERNARESH below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35335312/4941886)

Answer (score 10):

If you have other key bindings and dont want to reset the lot use: `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard`

Then find `Build.BuildSolution` or `Build.RebuildSolution` (on your preference) select `Global` in the `Use shortcut in` dropdown, place the cursor in `Press Shortcut Key` and slap <kbd>F6</kbd>.  It'll show you what it is currently assigned to, for me is was to traverse split panes (maybe it overrides <kbd>F6</kbd> when you use split panes for the first time?  I've always wondered why my home development machine built with <kbd>F6</kbd> and my work one doesn't and come to think of it I've never used split panes at home) then hit Assign.

Answer (score 6):

Its because you installed VMWare. It remaps that key so that F6 can be used to start debugging on a virtual machine.

Annoyed me too.

Comment: no.  I haven't installed VMWare.  Also, the menu option text changed to show Ctrl-Shift-B as build instead of F6.

Comment: i have upvoted that because that's definitely what happened to me

Comment: Add Parallels to VMWare.  "Show/hide application" in Parallels.

Answer (score 4):

You can reassign <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> to build the current project only:

1/  Go to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard`

2/  Show commands containing: `Build.BuildSelection`

3/  Focus the field `Press shortcut keys` & press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> to assign it

Answer (score 2):

Notepad++'s NPPscripting plugin broke Ctrl-Shift-B for my whole OS while NP++ was running. Uninstalling the plugin (I had to delete the DLL manually from the Notepad++ plugins folder) fixed the broken key mapping for me.

Comment: Yep that was it for me.  Thanks I never would have made that connection.

Comment: I wish I could upvote my own answer - it got me again! Thanks Google. Hey, you will all be this old one day. :p

Answer (score 1):

I had TPFanControl installed which captured <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> globally. I used a tool mentioned in [this answere](https://superuser.com/questions/57041/how-to-find-which-program-captures-global-keyboard-shortcut) to find out which program registered for which shortcuts.

Comment: Yep, TPFanControl it was. Don't run HotKey Commander under Windows 10 though. Things start crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a stale build in my solution (included libraries were apparently using old DLL versions and I was getting MissingMethodException's at runtime) so I deleted all the \bin directories in my C# projects, restarted Visual Studio, and suddenly this issue is now affecting me for the first time in the 3+ years since I started using Visual Studio.

No clue how this could have affected my user settings, but it apparently did. They went from using the "Visual C# 2005" keyboard profile to "default"

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard

search this command: "ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProjectBuild"

Assign F6

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2019, default keyboard mapping scheme is "Visual C# 2005"

When I **open a Git repo as a folder** (NOT open a VS solution), the "Build Solution" shortcut is **Shift+F6** (which does nothing, because there isn't a solution open, which can be built)

As soon as I **open a VS solution**, the "Build Solution" shortcut changes to **F6**.

So please check: Did you open a VS solution, or is a Git repo only open "as a folder"?