# Escape Doesn't Close Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio

I reinstalled VS2010 (new PC), and also installed VS2012. Both have the same issue: pressing escape does not close Intellisense, nor the method list (when you type a method name and press bracket, that little popup that appears showing you all overloaded versions).

How do I reinstate this? I checked through my keyboard settings but didn't find anything for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resetting my keyboard shortcuts fixed this:

- Tools > Options
- Environment > Keyboard
- Click "Reset" and Yes
- Fixed!

I am indebted to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854563/visual-studio-hot-keys-change-occasionally-specifically-f6-vs-ctrl-shift-b-for) (and comment) for an explanation:

> I have a theory. You type very fast... possible your opened a wormhole into the options screen as a result of fast typing and blew away the settings by accident? Just a thought.

Comment: has fixed nothing

Answer (score 5):

The keyboard command for it is, oddly, `Edit.SelectionCancel`, particularly in the "Text Editor" context.

The command also doubles as a useless deselect. Quite puzzling, like many other things in VS. I'd call it "IntellisenseClose" (and provide documentation for the available commands).

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it's a VS extension. Go into *Tools/Extensions* and disable them one by one.

Comment: I disabled them all (SlowCheetah and P4VS), and it still happens. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: this really helped.